# Using COG images uploaded to Amazon S3 ( private bucket) with credentials in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, authentication, cloud-optimized-geotiff, amazon-s3

I am creating a GIS webApp and trying to show GeoTIFF images as basemap with OpenLayers. This approach works perfectly as long as the corresponding URL is publicly accessible, like this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog.html.

This is my code:

```
const source = new ol.source.GeoTIFF({
  sources: [
    {
      url: 'cog image uploaded to amazon s3 with public url',
    },
  ],
});

const cogLayer = new ol.layer.WebGLTile({
    source: source,
    zIndex: 1,
    name: 'test',
  })
```

How can I reach that goal if the bucket is private and how to use authentication for access control?

Answer (score 1):

GeoTIFF source `ol.source.GeoTIFF` has option `sourceOptions` where you can specify additional options for geotiff.js on which OL GeoTIFF is based/dependent.

GeoTIFF source options (see [https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_GeoTIFF.html#~GeoTIFFSourceOptions](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_GeoTIFF.html#%7EGeoTIFFSourceOptions)) include `headers` and `credentials` options than can be used for authentication on Amazon S3. What should be specified there is outside GIS SE site scope.

Code could then look something like this:

```
const source = new ol.source.GeoTIFF({
  sources: [
    {
      url: 'cog image uploaded to amazon s3 with public url',
    },
  ],
  sourceOptions: {
    authentication: 'authentication data',
    headers: {
      'headerName1': 'header value 1',
      'headerName2': 'header value 2'
  }
});
```